# admin login and panel by next.js and typescript

Tags: next.js, types, tailwind-css

hi there so i need code for admin login after login dashboard part will show using of technology is next.js and tailwend css then typescript.

i need it guys as fresher you can all of stack people share tech knowledge..

Admin login and dashboard using technology is next.js ,typescript ,tailwind css

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.